# Effects to the microphone on the web

Tags: javascript, html, audio, streaming, web-audio-api

How I can get put an effect / filter to the microphone in HTML5? What I want is like this:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/testdrive/demos/microphone/

That is, you hear your voice live. I have to use HTML5, using any JS library if necessary.

Comment: Here's a bunch of effects, once you've got the mic input working; https://github.com/Theodeus/tuna

Answer (score 1):

The demo has a full source code available at

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/Demos/blob/master/microphone/scripts/demo.js

Basically it creates an audio context on a microphone and attaches different filters to it using Web Audio API.

Answer (score 1):

I also wrote a bunch of effects like this at https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/input/index.html, source code at https://github.com/cwilso/Audio-Input-Effects.